# How to extract single element from a tibble with a list column which is a list-of-lists with unequal dimensions?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I've got a tibble with a list column. Each element in that list column is a set of named key-value pairs, structured as a list of two lists. The key is called 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' and the value stored under 'FIELD_VALUE'.

The number of pairs for each row and the order of the pairs varies in the tibble. I want to search for rows in the tibble with a specific key ('CONTACT_FIELD_7') and value ('XYZ') pair.

My thinking is to somehow unnest the list column completely and add additional rows to the tible so each key-value pair has its own row. Then add two character columns to the tibble, one for the keys, and one for the values. However, then I'm still left with a list column with two lists (now with only a single element in each of them).

I also tried to find a way to search the strings in the list of lists.

This is the input:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_in <- tibble(CONTACT_ID = c(255381470, 255395936, 255400708, 255952013),
            CUSTOMFIELDS = list(list(list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_7', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'XYZ'), 
                                     list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = '123')),
                                list(list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'abc')),
                                list(list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'def'), 
                                     list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_3', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = '1234'),
                                     list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_7', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'XYZ')),
                                list(list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = '456'), 
                                     list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_7', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'ZYX'),
                                     list('CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' = 'CONTACT_FIELD_5', 
'FIELD_VALUE' = 'def'))))


# A tibble: 4 x 2
  CONTACT_ID CUSTOMFIELDS
       <dbl> <list>      
1  255381470 <list [2]>  
2  255395936 <list [1]>  
3  255400708 <list [3]>  
4  255952013 <list [3]>
```

The way I'm currently thinking an intermediate output would be

```
df_out_long <- tibble(CONTACT_ID = c(rep(255381470, 2), 255395936, rep(255400708, 3), rep(255952013, 3)),
                  CUSTOM_FIELD_ID = c('CONTACT_FIELD_7', 'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 
                                      'CONTACT_FIELD_2', 'CONTACT_FIELD_3', 'CONTACT_FIELD_7',
                                      'CONTACT_FIELD_1', 'CONTACT_FIELD_7', 'CONTACT_FIELD_5'),
                  FIELD_VALUE = c('XYZ', '123', 'abc', 'def', '1234', 'XYZ', '456', 'ZYX', 'def'))


# A tibble: 9 x 3
  CONTACT_ID CUSTOM_FIELD_ID FIELD_VALUE
       <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
1  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
2  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_1 123        
3  255395936 CONTACT_FIELD_2 abc        
4  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_2 def        
5  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_3 1234       
6  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
7  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_1 456        
8  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_7 ZYX        
9  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_5 def
```

Which can then easily be filtered to yield the final desired result

```
df_out_long %>% 
  filter(CUSTOM_FIELD_ID == 'CONTACT_FIELD_7', FIELD_VALUE == 'XYZ')

CONTACT_ID CUSTOM_FIELD_ID FIELD_VALUE
       <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
1  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
2  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ
```

## Where I'm stuck

The 'df_out_long' above may not be necessary at all as there may be a much more efficient way to do this. However, along this path I am able to unnest the deepest level of the list, which creates additional rows in the tibble to accommodate each key-value pair on a separate row. I can't seem to get rid of the list column with lists of length 2 that results and somehow flatten that into two character columns, names 'CUSTOM_FIELD_ID' and 'FIELD_VALUE'.

```
df_in %>%
  mutate_if(is.list, simplify_all) %>%
  unnest()

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  CONTACT_ID CUSTOMFIELDS
       <dbl> <list>      
1  255381470 <list [2]>  
2  255381470 <list [2]>  
3  255395936 <list [2]>  
4  255400708 <list [2]>  
5  255400708 <list [2]>  
6  255400708 <list [2]>  
7  255952013 <list [2]>  
8  255952013 <list [2]>  
9  255952013 <list [2]>
```

Comment: typo in construction of input tibble corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use `purrr::keep` to filter the lists themselves to only the elements you care about. Then one `unnest` will filter to the rows with something left, which you can then turn into a tibble so it can be neatly unnested.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_discarded <- df_in %>% mutate(CUSTOMFIELDS = map(
    CUSTOMFIELDS, keep, 
    ~.x$CUSTOM_FIELD_ID == 'CONTACT_FIELD_7' && .x$FIELD_VALUE == 'XYZ'
))

df_discarded
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   CONTACT_ID CUSTOMFIELDS
#>        <dbl> <list>      
#> 1  255381470 <list [1]>  
#> 2  255395936 <list [0]>  
#> 3  255400708 <list [1]>  
#> 4  255952013 <list [0]>

df_filtered <- df_discarded %>% unnest()
df_filtered
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   CONTACT_ID CUSTOMFIELDS
#>        <dbl> <list>      
#> 1  255381470 <list [2]>  
#> 2  255400708 <list [2]>

df_out <- df_filtered %>% 
    mutate(CUSTOMFIELDS = map(CUSTOMFIELDS, as_tibble)) %>% 
    unnest()

df_out
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   CONTACT_ID CUSTOM_FIELD_ID FIELD_VALUE
#>        <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
#> 1  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
#> 2  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ
```

Alternatively, if you want to grab everything and use `filter` at the end, `bind_rows` can turn named lists into tibbles, which can then be unnested:

```r
df_in %>% 
    mutate(CUSTOMFIELDS = map(CUSTOMFIELDS, bind_rows)) %>% 
    unnest()
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   CONTACT_ID CUSTOM_FIELD_ID FIELD_VALUE
#>        <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
#> 1  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
#> 2  255381470 CONTACT_FIELD_1 123        
#> 3  255395936 CONTACT_FIELD_2 abc        
#> 4  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_2 def        
#> 5  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_3 1234       
#> 6  255400708 CONTACT_FIELD_7 XYZ        
#> 7  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_1 456        
#> 8  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_7 ZYX        
#> 9  255952013 CONTACT_FIELD_5 def
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do that with bind_rows, very elegant solution!

Comment: Yep. It's often useful in the context of `map_dfr` (which uses `bind_rows` internally), because you can return named lists (which are often easier to generate) and get out a tibble. It seems to pop up a lot when using rvest and purrr together.

Comment: one little hiccup with the `bind_rows` implementation: it turns out in my actual data the FIELD_VALUE values are sometimes numeric and sometimes strings. `bind_rows` then throws an "can't be converted from numeric to character" error. Is there an easy way to force conversion of the FIELD_VALUE named list to character or would that mean using the other implementation?

Comment: You have to `map` `as.character` across each somehow. If you do it towards the end, you might not have to nest `map`s too deeply, or take care of it early by mapping recursively: `df_in %>% mutate(CUSTOMFIELDS = rapply(CUSTOMFIELDS, as.character, how = 'replace'))` up front. There's no purrr equivalent of `rapply`, though as long as the nesting is symmetric you can use `modify_depth` here: `df_in %>% mutate(CUSTOMFIELDS = modify_depth(CUSTOMFIELDS, -1, as.character))`. I happen to have just written [a blog post on the subject](https://alistaire.rbind.io/blog/recursion/).